# How can I change Explorer View permanently in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

I want to change the Explorer View setting permanently. But the default settings are restored after restarting Explorer. So how can I make these settings permanent?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% positive, however your Mac OSX theme might be the culprit.  Changing the `View` tab setting *should* permanently change the style.  Try removing the OS X theme and test.

Comment: Doesn't help me?

Comment: I agree that this is the most likely culprit.

Comment: re: "Doesn't help me"... Our task is to help you find the cause of the problem.  If your custom theme is causing a problem in windows Explorer, that isn't something we can fix.  All we can do is find the cause, and leave you to pursue a solution with the author of the theme itself.  Refusing to diagnose your own problem doesn't help anyone at all.

Comment: @Fopedush I tried to set the default XP theme but the result is same so thats why it didn't help me. Actually I've tried it before posted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open Explorer and go to `Tools->Folder Options` then click on the `View` tab and edit your settings there. You can then hit `Apply to All Folders` if you like and the view you've selected should stick.

Comment: Nopes doesn't work.

Comment: Did you modify the shell in some way? Keltari might be on the right direction, it may be the modified theme. On my stock XP system this method works properly, so something else is causing the reset.

Comment: Shell is change with the themes itself(I think). So if I change the theme then the shell should be change with it if not then how can I fix it?